# How to debug a release-only bug, seems to be some type of random corruption

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The bug will present itself only in release mode. And the bug presents it self in a slightly random manner but I have managed to reproduce it enough times to say it's reproducible.

I have tried debugging the app using debug heap and _CrtCheckMemory() but it always returns 1 meaning there doesn't appear to be any heap corruption.

In debug mode it works without error, in release mode, it sometimes works without error. This is why I believe it's some type of corruption problem. The bug does not produce any type of crash or signal, it's just doing something wrong in the application.

How can I try to solve this? I also tried turning off the debug heap while debugging to see if could get the error to happen in that state, but I couldn't.

Comment: Make the Release build include debug information in the build.

Comment: Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx

Comment: From my experience debugging sneaky issues like this, it's probably a use-after-free.  Use-after-free problems can be very sneaky, and can slip through heap corruption detection (since that only works if heap control structures are damaged, not data which lives on the heap).  Double check any complicated memory management or object life cycles that may be present.

Comment: Burn the forest. Make a copy of the release build and simplify it without mercy, checking for the bug after every brutal excision. If you reach a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without finding the bug, let us know.